# How to set background color for long in-text citations with line wrapping?

Tags: color, citing, highlighting, soul

Normally for revised-version, the revised text should be highlighted. When it contains long in-text citations which span more than one line, the background color will extend to the margin, and whatever left in the citation on the next line does not have background color.

What I use now is `\usepackage{soul} \soulregister\cite7 \soulregister\citep7` , I know this problem is because `\soulregister` put the in-text citations in `\mbox`.

I tried `tcolorbox , tikz`, but they are like boxes.

**What I want is just to have a block of text with background color, with citations across more than one line with background color within the block of text. No need to be restricted in using `soul` package.**

Wonder whether this is possible for latex? Any help appreciated!

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{soul}
\soulregister\cite7
\soulregister\citep7

\begin{filecontents*}{bibtest.bib}
    @article{r14,
        author = {Tavakoli, R and Mura, P},
        title = {Netnography in tourism - Beyond Web 2.0},
        journal = {Annals of Tourism Research},
        year = {2018},
        volume = {73},
        pages = {190-192},
    }
    @article{r15,
        author = {Ahmad, M and Sattar, Y},
        title = {A Factors influencing Customer Satisfaction in Hotel Industry: A Case of Pakistan},
        journal = {Journal of Business and Finance Management Research},
        year = {2018},
        volume = {4},
        pages = {5-11},
    }
    @article{r16,
        author = {Gilbert, G R and Veloutsou, C and Goode, M M H and et al},
        title = {Measuring customer satisfaction in the fast food industry},
        journal = {Journal of Services Marketing},
        year = {2004},
        volume = {18},
        number = {5},
        pages = {371-383},
    }
    @article{r17,
        author = {Anderson, E W and Fornell, C and Lehmann, D R},
        title = {Customer Satisfaction, Market Share, and Profitability},
        journal = {Journal of Marketing},
        year = {1994},
        volume = {58},
        pages = {53-66},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    
    \hl{werwe Etiam \citep{r14} suscipit \citep{r14,r15,r16,r17} Donec Fusce ornare. 
        
        Proin ipsum enim \cite{r15,r16,r17} aliquam
    }
    
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{bibtest}
    
\end{document}
```

The result with the background color problem:

[image: background color problem]

Comment: use lualatex and the lua-ul package.

Comment: Thanks, but quite a lot errors pointing to the lua-ul.sty, the first line is: `Undefined control sequence. \ProvidesExplPackage `. I am using Texlive 2019.

Comment: then make a choice: don't highlight or update your texsystem. soul can't handle such cite commands as it can't expand them and so don't know how much place they occupy.

Comment: I tried using `Overleaf.com` for testing, and found that only the version `Texlive 2021` could accept `lua-ul.sty` to work, even the `Texlive 2020` cannot. Anyway, this looks like the ONLY way till today. @Ulrike Fischer
 Could you write a separate post please and I will accept as the answer.